# Converting WP theme to Genesis

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I am new to Genesis Framework. I have installed the plugin and Genesis Sample Child theme. Now I want to copy my previous theme styles and functions how do I do that? I have copied Styles.css from my previous theme child theme but its not getting same results. Also how do I override my functions

Answer (score 3):

The styles and functions from your previous theme are going to apply to the elements and templates of your previous theme. It's quite likely that what you're attempting to do will be impossible, or at least too big of a task to be worth it. Genesis is a great place to start when building a new custom theme, but it already has its own templates, styles and functions defined that are not going to play well with another theme that wasn't built in Genesis.